# RoR XML API says route not found. manually adding route doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, api, routes

The command I'm trying to execute from the terminal:

```
curl "http://acme.example.com/controller_name/destroy.xml?api_key=123&id=150&other_id=430"
```

Just a simple GET request, nothing special there.

But when I do that, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError 
(No route matches "/controller_name/destroy.xml" with 
{:remote_ip=>"127.0.0.1", 
 :accepts=>"*/*", 
 :protocol=>"http://", 
 :subdomain=>"acme", 
 :method=>:get, 
 :request_uri=>"/controller_name/destroy.xml?api_key=123&id=150&other_id=430", 
 :port=>80, 
 :content_type=>nil, 
 :domain=>"example.com"}):
```

So then I added this to my routes.rb file:

```
  map.connect "/controller_name/destroy", :controller => :controller_name, :action => :destroy
```

But I get the same error, so the route I added doesn't help at all.

Here is the destroy method from controller_name

```
  def destroy
    @other = Other.find(params[:other_id])
    attachment = @other.attachments.find(params[:id])
    attachment.destroy

    @attachments = @other.attachments

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml do
        head :ok 
      end
    end
  end
```

In routes.rb, the controller_name is just included this way:

```
  map.resources :others, :has_many => [:controller_names]
```

and all the AJAX things already in the controller work fine... even for the same method, calling destroy with an AJAX request works.... but not the XML portion..... >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the format on the request.

```
map.connect "/controller_name/destroy(.:format)", :controller => :controller_name, :action => :destroy
```

Comment: thanks, just had to remove the parathesis to get it to work. =D

Comment: actually, adding this line causes a problem with the rest of the actions.

Comment: I think my problem is deeper than this. but since this solved my question, but broke the rest of the controller, I'll go ahead and accept it.